# How to hide an <a> element for 5 secs after clicking on it?

Tags: jquery

How to hide an `<a>` element for 5 secs after clicking on it

I found this: but not working.

```
$('a.rate-number-up-down-btn-up').hide('blind', {}, 5000);
```

Comment: That line looks to be using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/effect/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
$('a.rate-number-up-down-btn-up').hide(500).delay(5000).show(500);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vd2rB/**

Or without an effect:

```
$('a.rate-number-up-down-btn-up').hide(0).delay(5000).show(0);
```

You still need to pass in `0` for the duration, as without an effect queue, `.delay()` doesn't do anything.

Comment: I was wondering why:$('div').hide().delay(5000).show(); wasn't working, no i know, we have to pass some duration to make it animate just like this: $('div').hide(0).delay(5000).show(0);  Thx Blender you save me some time

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
$('a.rate-number-up-down-btn-up').hide({
  'effect':'blind'
}, 5000, function() {
  $(this).show(); 
});
```

Also made it do the reverse:

```
$('a.rate-number-up-down-btn-up').hide({
  'effect':'blind'
}, 5000, function() {
  $(this).show({
    'effect':'blind'
  }, 5000); 
});
```

Comment: Updated answer, sorry about that.

Comment: Note however this doesn't actually hide it for 5 seconds, it instead hides it OVER 5 seconds, it isn't actually hidden till the end, where it is instantly shown again.

Comment: how do I remove the blind effect to hide in mediately ?

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed probably works but you are just either not including the jQuery UI library or you are using the wrong selector

```
<a class="click"> Click me</a>
```

Then the jquery code to do that is:

```
 $('a.click').hide('blind', {}, 5000);
```

Provided you include [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com), since you are using the `blind` effect.